# "I major in accounts" vs. "My major is accounts"

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

> I major in accounts
>
> My major is accounts.

Please let me know which of the two is more natural.

This is how I will introduce myself.

Comment: You probably mean "head of accounts" or "accounting manager"?

Comment: Are you a college student and you're trying to describe what you are studying?  In English that field of study is called "accounting", not "accounts".

Comment: **Accounting** is the study of the financial **accounts** of a company.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean "major" as in the [primary field of study of your degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_(academic)). If this is the case, I would not call either of your sentences natural, and your second sentence I would say is not correct.

An issue with both of your sentences is that the field is [*accounting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accounting) (or *accountancy*), not *accounts*. You might say "I work in accounts," meaning you work in a company department responsible for [book-keeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookkeeping), where "accounts" refers to the *accounts department* and not *accountancy*.

---

> I major in accounting.

This sentence is grammatically correct, but is not the accepted way of stating your field of study. This sentence sounds like the "general truth" present tense – that is, a statement of something that is always true, or is a constant characteristic of something.

There are several ways you could phrase the sentence, depending on whether you are studying:

> I **am majoring** in accounting.
>   *You are currently or will in future study accounting.*
>
> I **majored** in accounting.
>   *You are not currently studying accounting, but have studied it in the past.*
>
> I **will be majoring** in accounting.
>   I **will major** in accounting.
>   *You will in future study accounting.*

---

> My major is accounting.

This sentence is not correct, a major is always "in" the field. If you want to use a sentence of this form (rather than of the previously-discussed form), you must use "in":

> My major is **in** accounting.

---

As to which is a better sentence to use, either is fine.

You might use one of the forms of the first sentence if you wanted to emphasize when studying of the major occurred. The second sentence works whether you are currently studying, studied in the past, or will study in future, but note that the future meaning only makes sense if you are currently enrolled on a course, or have accepted an offer for that course.

Comment: +1, but in my sociolect it's entirely proper to ask "What's your major?" and get "My major's Accounting, but my minor's English" as a response.

Answer (score 1):

*Accounts* may be the financial and production data a firm keeps; or the books or digital files in which the data are kept; or distinct datasets associated with individual customers or clients; or the customers/clients themselves. But if you are speaking of a university course of study (which is what "major" suggests to a US reader: your *major* is the primary discipline to which your study is directed), the term you want is ***accounting*** in the US (I believe it's called "accountancy" in the UK).

And the natural way of saying this is

> I'm majoring in Accounting.